# 'str' object is not callable using enumerate

Tags: python

I'm trying to do the following:

```
for index, image_properties in enumerate(list_of_properties):
    index = str(index)
```

But I keep getting

```
TypeError at /
'str' object is not callable
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a variable named str somewhere earlier? Because that's what it looks like. For instance: `str = "red"; str(1)` returns that exact error.

Comment: @Josiah I agree, Try re-opening your interpreter and be careful not to use `built-in` names for your variables.

Comment: Try `str = __builtins__.str` if you don't want to restart the interpreter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the commenters have mentioned, you must have `str` defined somewhere and it overrides the `str` built-in function.

In Python you can easily "re-bind" symbols like this. See this session for example:

```
>>> str(2)
'2'
>>> def str(x): return x + 1
... 
>>> str(2)
3
>>> str = 1
>>> str(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Moreover the text of *your* `TypeError` suggests that `str` was defined to be a string object somewhere earlier.